# Can't change base color of icing

Tags: color

[image]

[image]following blender guru in his donut tutorial i found a problem with donut. i simply can't choose an ordinary color it shows me some options to choose from

Comment: Change the surface from principled to emission and back to principled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have plugged the *Color* output of an *Object Info* node into the *Base Color* of the *Principled BSDF*. I would suggest you switch to the [*Shading* workspace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/workspaces.html) to properly see the nodes in the [*Shader Editor*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html). Then unplug the incorrect node connection and adjust the *Base Color* to your liking.

Alternatively, if you want to only use the *Material Properties* instead of the *Shader Editor*, click on the *Base Color* like in your screenshot and select *Remove*.

Comment: thanks! i just found out that i am missing texture paint node as i formatted my pc without saving the texture paint image on internet XD

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.